# Calculating the inverse of the beta cumulative probability density in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jstat

I need to duplicate the functionality of this EXCEL function in JavaScript - the inverse of the beta cumulative probability density http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/beta-inv-function-HP010335670.aspx.

Is there a  JS library which offers this? I've tried Jstat (http://www.jstat.org/) but it does not appear to have this particular calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this by building a more up to date version of the jStat Library from here: https://github.com/jstat/jstat

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is that you want, but did you heard of [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/)?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for a charting library in this case - I will be needing one later so will evaluate this one in time :)